# Make subplots from scatter plot using PCA values to visualize them better

Tags: python, scikit-learn, plotly, pca

I'm doing a PCA from my dataset that has a shape of (100, 103), and I want to do a PCA from the the first 60 variables, I followed this code from plotly

https://plotly.com/python/pca-visualization/

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


n_components = 60

pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
components = pca.fit_transform(df)

total_var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() * 100

labels = {str(i): f"PC {i+1}" for i in range(n_components)}


targets = ['0', '1']
colors = ['b', 'r']

fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    components,
    color=target,
    dimensions=range(n_components),
    labels=labels,
    title=f'Total Explained Variance: {total_var:.2f}%',
)
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

But of course, this is not readable[image: Visualization PCA], I was wondering if there is any way that I can do a visualization of my PCA results either using subplots or similar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The plot here ends up with a 60x60 scatter matrix, that number of components is not reasonable for data visualization. You could instead make PCA() select the number of PCs such that the amount of variance that needs to be explained is greater than a percentage you specify (with 0 < n_components < 1), ie. `pca = PCA(n_components=0.9)` selects the number of PCs that keep 90% of the variance, then to retrieve that number `pca.n_components_`.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously unreadable, cause you are trying to display a 60*60 matrix.
Try to display first five components or less (the number of components displayed is limited by the `cutoff` variable)

```
n_components = 60

df = np.random.rand(100,103)
pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
components = pca.fit_transform(df)

cutoff = 5
explained_var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_[:cutoff].sum()

labels = {str(i): f"PC {i+1}" for i in range(cutoff)}

fig = px.scatter_matrix(components[:,:cutoff], dimensions=range(cutoff),
    title=f'Total Explained Variance: {explained_var*100:.2f}%',)
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.show()
```